# groovy-all is not Included When Installing with Maven

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I am trying to create a simple project where I use maven to manage dependencies and using groovy as the main script.

I've included all the necessary libraries to run the groovy script

here is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.randomperson.hello</groupId>
  <artifactId>TryMaven</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>TryMaven</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.7</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement
    ><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.randomperson.hello.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.0</version>
                    </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8-01</version>
          </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

when i install using `mvn clean install` the build is successful but when i tried to execute the .jar file using `java -jar file.jar` it gives this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.randomperson.hello.App
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
```

I am not quite sure how groovy work with maven but it seems that it does not include the groovy library specifically the groovy-all which is declared in dependencies.

I am using OpenJDK11 & Groovy 4.0.2

am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have anything in the maven build that is configured to create a standalone fat jar?  By default, the jar that is created should not include its dependencies.

Comment: The groovy-all jar was deprecated in 2.4. From 2.5 Groovy consists of multiple jar files.